# TypeError and AttibuteError on Temperature Converter GUI in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am trying to understand the codes wrote by someone else so that I can build my own GUI.

Here is the code.

MODEL: temperatureconvert.py

```
class TemperatureConvert:
    """
    class TemperatureCovert is the MODEL for a simple program. It just converts temperature
    in Celisus into Fahrenheit and vice versa.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace = 0
        self.celsiusEntrySpace = 0

    def convertTempF2C(self):
        fahrenheit = self.fahrenheitEntrySpace
        if fahrenheit != 0.0:
             celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
        else:
             celsius = -17.7777778 

    def convertTempC2F(self):
        celsius = self.celsiusEntrySpace
        if celsius != 0.0:
             fahrenheit = (celsius *  9.0/5.0 + 32)          
        else:
             fahrenheit = 32

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.counter)
```

VIEW: myFrame10.py

```
import tkinter

class MyFrame(tkinter.Frame): #creates window for controls in an object made
                          #from a class called "tkinter.Frame" 
    """
    Class myFrame is the VIEW for a simple program that contains two buttons,     two entry areas, and four labels:
    one button a converter;
    one button quits the program;
    one entry is for celsius;
    one entry is for fahrenheit;
    and the labels prompt user for input, and label the entry values as needed.
    """

    def __init__(self, controller):
        """
        places the controls on the frame
        """
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self) #initilizes the superclass 
        self.pack()  #required for the buttons to show up properly.
        self.controller = controller #saves ref to controller to call methods on
                                      #contoller object when user generates events

#Fahrenheit Input Prompt
        self.fahrenheitLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.fahrenheitLabel["text"] = "Enter Fahrenheit Value:"
        self.fahrenheitLabel.pack({"side":"left"})

#Fahrenheit Entry Space
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace.insert(0, "FahrenheitTemperature")  
        self.fahrenheitEntrySpace.pack({"side":"left"})

#Fahrenheit Value label
        self.fahrenheitLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.fahrenheitLabel["text"] = ("Fahrenheit Degrees")
        self.fahrenheitLabel.pack({"side":"left"})

#Converter button 
        self.convertButton=tkinter.Button(self)
        self.convertButton["text"]= "Convert"
        self.convertButton["command"]=self.controller.buttonPressed
        # an object that remembers both self and reply when later called
        self.convertButton.pack({"side":"left"})       

#Quit button
        self.quitButton = tkinter.Button(self)
        self.quitButton["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.quitButton["command"] = self.quit
        #the statement above attaches the event handler
        #self.quit() to the quit button
        self.quitButton.pack({"side":"right"})

#Celsius Value label
        self.celsiusLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.celsiusLabel["text"] = ("Celsius Degrees")
        self.celsiusLabel.pack({"side":"right"})

#Celsius Entry Space
        self.celsiusEntrySpace = tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.celsiusEntrySpace.insert(0, "CelsiusTemperature")
        self.celsiusEntrySpace.pack({"side":"right"})


#Celsius Input Prompt
        self.celsiusLabel = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.celsiusLabel["text"] = ("Enter Celsius Value:")
        self.celsiusLabel.pack({"side":"right"})
```

CONTROLLER: controller10.py

```
import tkinter

import myFrame10 #the VIEW

import temperatureconvert #the MODEL

class Controller:

    """
    The CONTROLLER for an app that follows the MODEL/VIEW/CONTROLLER architecture.
    When the user presses a button on the VIEW,
    this controller calls the appropriate methods in the model.
    The controller handles all the communication between the model and the view.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        """
        This starts the TK framework up;
        instantiates the model;
        instantiates the VIEW;
        and states the event loop that waits for the user to press a button on the view
        """
        root = tkinter.Tk() #This starts the TK framework up;
        self.model = temperatureconvert.TemperatureConvert() #instantiates the model
        self.view = myFrame10.MyFrame(self) #instantiates the VIEW
        self.view.mainloop() # states event loop waits for user to press button on view
        root.destroy() #lets user quit

    def buttonPressed(self):

        """
        Convert F --> C
        """

        self.model.convertTempF2C(self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.get)
        #MODEL creates new celsius temp from(fahrenheit input) 

        self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.clear()
        #replaces VIEW's old default celsius value

        self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.insert(self.model.celsius)
        #and insert's MODEL's newly converted (celsius) value

        """
        Convert C --> F
        """

        self.model.convertTempC2F(self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.get)
        #MODEL creates new fahrenheit temp from  (celsius input)

        self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.pop() 
        #replaces VIEW's old default 0 fahrenheit value 

        self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.insert(self.model.fahrenheit)
        #and insert's MODEL's newly converted (fahrenheit) value

if __name__=="__main__":
    c = Controller()
```

First of all, I got an TypeError as below.

> > > ```
> > > Exception in Tkinter callback
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >   File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
> > >     return self.func(*args)
> > >   File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/10X Genomics/Python exercise/controller10.py", line 36, in buttonPressed
> > >     self.model.convertTempF2C(self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.get)
> > > TypeError: convertTempF2C() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
> > > ```

However, I don't know what part goes wrong under method of convertTempF2c().

Second, how could I remove the "celsiusEntrySpace" default value (in this case, it is CelsiusTemperature) with the new value obtain from converting Fahrenheit? .pop is not working in this case since it only works on the list, and it gave the error below.

> > > ```
> > > Exception in Tkinter callback
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >   File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
> > >     return self.func(*args)
> > >   File "/Users/adrian/Desktop/10X Genomics/Python exercise/controller10.py", line 39, in buttonPressed
> > >     self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.pop()
> > > AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'pop'
> > > ```

So, how could I fix those 2 errors above? Please help! Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

`convertTempF2C` looks like the following; notice that it takes no positional parameters other than `self`:

```
def convertTempF2C(self):
```

However, you're calling it like this:

```
self.model.convertTempF2C(self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.get)
```

There are two things wrong with that line. First, you're passing an extra parameter which the function isn't expecting. Second, you're not actually *calling* the `get` function, you're merely *referencing* it. You should call it like this:

```
value = self.view.fahrenheitEntrySpace.get()
self.model.convertTempF2C(value)
```

Note the trailing parenthesis on that first line.

Why two steps instead of one? It makes the code clearer, and it makes it easier to debug because you can print out the value before doing the conversion to verify it is what you think it is.

Finally, you are doing this:

```
self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.pop()
```

Just as the error message is telling you, `self.view.celsiusEntrySpace` is an Entry widget, and Entry widgets don't have a pop method. I don't know why you think it does, unless you're going by some incorrect documentation. I also don't quite understand what you *think* this is doing, so I can't offer an alternative.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation on the first question. It makes sense now to me. For the second question, the pop method was what I got. But, I think the idea is to remove the default value (CelsisuTemperature) in the Celsius Entry Space and update it with the numerical value after conversion. Since there are 2 Entry widgets for each Fahrenheit and Celsius, I would like to use both if I enter value for Fah and value of Celsius will appear after press convert, and vice versa. If so, how should I fix it if I would like to do this? Otherwise, do I need to create another 2 labels?

Comment: After following what you suggested earliest for the first question, why do I still get the same TypeError:convertTempF2C() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given?

Comment: @WuChu: because, like the error states, the function accepts only one parameter but you are giving it two. Either change what it accepts, or change what you are giving it.

Comment: How do I change into only give 1 but not 2?

Comment: @WuChu: when you do `self.model.convertTempF2C()` it gets one positional parameter: `self`. When you do `self.model.converTempF2C(something)`, it gets two: `self` and `something`.

Comment: So, I fixed it to only accept only 1 positional parameter while giving only 1. Here is the revised version, so now there is no more error. However, I don't see my correct output value for the Celsius after input Fahrenheit, and both entry space will show "None" after press Convert. Do you know why it cause this?

Comment: """
        Convert F --> C
        """

    
        self.model.convertTempF2C()
        #MODEL creates new celsius temp from(fahrenheit input) 

        self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.delete(0, "end")
        #replaces VIEW's old default celsius value

        self.view.celsiusEntrySpace.insert(0,str(self.model.convertTempF2C()))
        #and insert's MODEL's newly converted (celsius) value

Comment: @WuChu: stackoverflow isn't designed for discussions. If you have additional questions, please ask them as actual questions rather than comments to an answer.